# How to get all the items of a dropdown list to gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I need to display all the items of a ddl to gridview in asp.net. How to achieve that? 
My aspx code is

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>--Select-- </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>

    <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pakistan</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
  <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="Grd1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

My aspx.cs code is

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Country"] = DDLCountry.Items;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    Grd1.DataSource = dt;
    Grd1.DataBind();


}
```

Comment: `Grd1.DataSource = DDLCountry.Items.Select(li=>li.Text); Grd1.DataBind();` should work, but the `DDLCountry` should be databound first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
foreach(ListItem item in DDLCountry.Items)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr.SetField("Country",item .Text);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
Grd1.DataSource = dt;
Grd1.DataBind();
```

or the minimized version:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Country");  // string is default
foreach (string country in DDLCountry.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text))
    dt.Rows.Add(country);
```